# Python Socket does not receive message

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have a Python socket established in my server.py file and a client that connects to it in my client.py file. It worked fine the first I ran both scripts in my command line but now every time I run them I get:

> OSError: [Errno 48] Address is already in use

but the server.py file still seems to run just fine even with that error. However my client.py file is not receiving a message that I am trying to send.

```
#server.py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection from {address} has been established.') 
    #this prints as expected
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Test Message", "utf-8"))
```

My print statement works just fine even though I receive the `Address is already in use error`.

```
#client.py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))


msg = s.recv(1024)

print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Nothing is printing from my client.py file so I assume that it is not receiving the message. I suspect that it is caused by the error that it is giving but I am unsure how to fix it.

What is the best way to close all of the current connections? Also, is this related to the connections already being opened? Is there a way to be certain that the message is being sent and that my client is receiving it? Below is how I am running the scripts if it is relevant.

`python3 server.py & python3 client.py`

Comment: I believe you're trying to handle multiple client connections, but only allowing the server to handle the client one at a time. You need to implement threading in your server script. If you give me a minute, I'll be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Sounds good Id appreciate it.

Comment: Your code is running fine on my end. Are you sure you're not just attempting to run `server.py` multiple times? Try opening two different command prompts and running each command separately. In one terminal, run `python server.py`. In the other terminal, run `python client.py`. Now every time you run client.py in that terminal, it should be getting the message. And on your server terminal, you should be getting messages that the connection was made.

Comment: I guess you're right, it works fine if I add `s.close()` at the end of  the program and change my port number. However because I did not have `s.close()` when I was using port 1234, so is there a way that I can close all instances or connections on port 1234 so I can continue using them without having to worry about forgetting to add `s.close()` in the future?

Comment: Just in case I forget to `s.close()` it would be nice to know of a more efficient way rather than having to change the port number every time I run it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're getting at. You want to be able to run multiple instances of server.py on the same computer/server? If that's the case, you will have to change the port number because the previous instance of server.py is already using that port. Also, I would like to direct you to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QiPPX-KeSc) which explains socket programming very well. I'm not sure if stack overflow likes people giving recommendations like this or not but oh well.

Comment: You really need an event loop. An easy and modern example of that is here: https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#how-do-you-write-a-tcp-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `server.py`, immediately after you create the socket, try adding:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

The `SOL_SOCKET` option specifies that the setting applies to the socket API in a protocol-independent manner, as opposed to a specific protocol, such as TCP. The `SO_REUSEADDR` option with the value of `1` enables the address to be re-used as long as the socket is in `TIME_WAIT` state, meaning that it has been closed, but is being held for a short while to allow any remaining packets to arrive and be identified with that connection. If the socket is in any other active state, you will still get the `address already in use` error.

This isn't a cure-all for all socket issues, but it may allow the server to re-bind to the port if it's spending too long in `TIME_WAIT` status.

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation of the parameters on this method?

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I notice that if I use this with `s.close()` and I ensure that I exit my `while` loop everything seems to work. I just need to make sure that I break out of my loop and using this works.

Answer (score 0):

Both the files are working fine for me.
Try using another port instead of `1234`

Comment: Yes they work one time for me, I guess I need to figure out how I can call them multiple times without error on the second and third try.